# how to search for a specific string in a file in python?

Tags: python, file

Hi all I am newbie in python and I want to know how to search for data in this txt file in the link
where the user will input the name of the car and the app should search the file and print the line back
here is my code I tried to input Kia Optima LX 4dr for search but it not work

```
search = input('enter the car name you want to look for')
searchByName(search)

def searchByName(search):
    outfile = open('cars.txt','r')
    for line in outfile:
        if search in outfile:
            print(line)
            break
    print('no car is found with this name')
```

any help would be appreciated

[the txt file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iEstFXr-pWo4X0p-G5xDCcufOxgObyzu/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

Comment: Your immediate problem is your `if` condition: you're comparing a string to a file handle; these will *never* be equal.  Instead, try `if search in line`.  You should learn basic debugging skills **now**, developing good coding practices.  One or two simple `print` statements would have shown you the error.

Comment: thank this solve my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're dealing with tabular data. I would suggest to use Pandas in this case to read the data, name the columns and use Pandas functions as opposed to writing your own solution. Something like:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_fwf('cars.txt', header=None)

df[df[0].str.contains('Chevrolet Impala')]
                          0   1   2   3   4   5   ...  13  14    15   16   17  18
50      Chevrolet Impala 4dr   0   0   0   0   0  ...  21  32  3465  111  200  73
105  Chevrolet Impala LS 4dr   0   0   0   0   0  ...  20  30  3476  111  200  73
106  Chevrolet Impala SS 4dr   0   0   0   0   0  ...  18  28  3606  111  200  73

[3 rows x 19 columns]
```